How to calculate the rate of convergence of a series when it's not known for which value the series converges to?
What would be the rate of convergence of a double series in the form of
$$
T[r,z,t]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\kappa\ f_{nm}[r]\ g_{nm}[z]\ h_{nm}[t]
$$
where $\kappa$ is a constant and $f_{nm},\ g_{nm}$ and $h_{nm}$ are combinations of many other functions as, trigonometric, hyperbolic, Bessel, Erf and exponentials. Is there a general method? I'm trying to find the rate of convergence of a series which is the solution for a PDE and I know the series is convergent, but in my case the combination of $f_{nm},\ g_{nm}$ and $h_{nm}$ generated more than ten terms, so I tried to keep as brief as possible here.

Can you give (or bound) the asymptotic behavior of the terms for large $m$ or $n$?  That would seem to be the only general way to approach it.
